# Should I use a Squid on the host machine or a virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, squid, proxmox

I have a server from SoYouStart and 32 failover IPs.

I need these IPs for proxy (for scraping). Should I set up Squid on the host machine (Proxmox) or on a virtual machine like Ubuntu + Squid?

I read the Proxmox documentation and saw that if I want to add 32 failover IPs (in one block), I must add each IP as a separate network interface?